# Associate a contact with its Account

Tags: campaign-influence

Want to export account information with the contact(s) associated with it including their email and import to Pardot to create a drip marketing campaign.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off querying directly on the Contact object, and include parent fields from Account and the Contact fields you need. Not sure what you're using, but using Data Loader or Workbench:

```
SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact ...
```